# C# (find second largest number) How to split program in subprograms ?so I can reuse code later...?

Tags: c#

I have this program that finds second largest number from users input, user needs to input atleast 2 numbers and maximum 10. I want to split program into subprograms(at least main and one function). And i cant get it to work :(

Org. code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 1, max = 0, smax = 0, i = 0, ISsmaxrepeating = 0;

        while (n != 0 && i < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input number");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //I want this part to be in a function from here.
            if (n > max)
            {
                smax = max;
                max = n;
            }
            else if (n > smax)
            {
                smax = n;
            }
            //to here
            if (n == smax)
            {
                ISsmaxrepeating = n; // checks if there are 2 numbers smax. Example: 2 1 1  it outputs error
            }

            i++;
        }
        if (smax != 0 && smax != ISsmaxrepeating)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("secondmax is {0}", smax);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

So far I come up with this but it is not working :(

```
 static int checking(int n, int max, int smax)
    {
        if (n > max)
        {
            smax = max;
            max = n;
        }
        else if (n > smax)
        {
            smax = n;
        }
        return n;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 1, max = 0, smax = 0, i = 0, ISsmaxrepeating = 0, result = 0;

        while (n != 0 && i < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input number");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            result = checking(n,max,smax);

            if (n == smax)
            {
                ISsmaxrepeating = n; // checks if there are 2 numbers smax. Example: 2 1 1  it outputs error
            }

            i++;
        }
        if (smax != 0 && smax != ISsmaxrepeating)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("secondmax is {0}", smax);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Comment: dont u have to use `if (n == result)` rather than `smax`?, you are not doing anything with th result returned from `checking` method.

Comment: ye true that... but that doesnt help me.. Idk how can i return from checking() max, smax and n :(

Comment: You code is very complicated  You don;'t need both 'i' & 'n'.  One issue is when you get the first input how do you get the 2nd largest number when you have only one input?

Comment: *edited: user need to input atleast 2 numbers and maximum 10

Comment: other than that it is simple algorithm

Comment: ur code works without the function?

Comment: yup it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output multiple variables from the function using `ref` keyword. However, it's better not to use a function for this kind of operation.

```
static void checking(int n, ref int max, ref int smax)
{
    if (n > max)
    {
        smax = max;
        max = n;
    }
    else if (n > smax)
    {
        smax = n;
    }
}
```

Call the function inside `Main`

```
checking(n, ref max, ref smax);
```

Comment: Why it is not good to use function for this kind of operation ? Do you think there is better way for spliting up this program into smaller chunks ? :)

Comment: Because you are passing all the variables required from `Main` and it does simple calculations then return multiple variables which can be done easily in the `Main` method itself, also your `checking()` function doesn't get called from elsewhere.

Comment: yeah i know..., but it is requirement for me to use atleast one function or procedure in school exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont.you use Math.max or Math.min? If.you want to find highest between 3 numbes, first do int halfmax=math.max(firstnum,secondnum)
then do int max = Math.max(halfmaz,thirdnum).

Comment: beacuse i'm not aloud to use math function in this section of exercises